# how to get dimension of a 2-D array in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I am passing a two dimensional array to a method and in the method I want to calculate the dimension of the array. I am able to calculate the number of elements by

```
length = (sizeof(data)/(sizeof(data[0]));
```

but i am not able to get the number of rows and columns.

I tried to create a 2-D NSArray from the given array but was unable to do it without the size of array.

Comment: Show how you're creating these arrays

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:nsmutablearray] but... why?

Comment: Please explain how this is Objective-C or `NSArray` related. Your code snippet shows pure C arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = (sizeof(data)/(sizeof(0[data]));
cols = (sizeof(0[data])/(sizeof(0[data][0]));
```

Comment: fancy subscript swap syntax

Comment: thanks Cy-4AH for your answer